# Android Service stops after the app is killed

Tags: android, service, android-service

I want to create a `service` that runs even when the app is closed from the Task manager. I have created a service and then Logged a message to check if it's running and I noticed that it works only if if the app is running or in foreground.

**Service class:**

```
public class CallService extends Service {

    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    protected Handler handler;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public CallService getService() {
            return CallService .this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("TESTINGSERVICE", "Service is running");
    }
}
```

**Starting the service from my MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   startService(new Intent(this, CallService.class));
```

**Manifest**

```
<application>
   ...
   <service
      android:name=".activities.services.CallService">
   </service>
</application>
```

What changes do I have to make? Thanks, folks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your service, add the following code.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
    restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 }
```

Comment: My phone is so brutal that it's been killing foreground services the moment the app is closed. I tried this and this too failed :( Using an Oppo A3S