# i register broadcastreceiver about screen_on,but i can not receive it

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i register a broadcastReceiver about screen_on,but when i click power_on button,i can not receive it

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
mBatInfoReceiver=new BatInfoReceiver();
registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, filter);

public  class BatInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
//                String action = intent.getAction();
//                if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
//
//                }
            Log.d("BatInfoReceiver","111111");
            getGestureData();
            myView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your app has to be running to receive that intent I think.

Comment: is that i power_off to close my screen,my app is not running?

Comment: Did you register a broadcast receiver in your manifest?

Comment: no ,i did not register it in manifest,i register it only in activity

Comment: you are doing to be banned for using rood language

Comment: what is rood language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver for SCREEN\_ON and SCREEN\_OFF even after quitting the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324659/broadcastreceiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off-even-after-quitting-the-app)